# How to set width of form to auto adjust to width of datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to set the width of my form to automatically resize depending on width of the datagridview, case is in the picture:[image]

So basically I want to remove horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: IMHO that sounds like bad design, the user should control the size of the window, especially if it's that large. I'd be very annoyed if the window kept forcing itself to be huge and take up my monitor. Anchor the DataGridView to the form and let the user decide whether horizontal scrollbars are acceptable.

Comment: Problem with anchor is that i have 2 buttons on the form, and thing is, that datagrid view isnt gonna be that large, it will mainly have the same width all the time,only the last column will be little bit larger. I understand ur thinking when you say "bad design", but if i let user decide on resizing the window, that doesnt help coz he cannot resize the datagridview

Comment: I don't understand why anchoring is a problem or why they can't resize the DGV. If you anchor the DGV on all four sides it will resize with the form and not overlap the buttons.

Comment: call me stupid, but this happends when i dock the container: http://prntscr.com/ef1knk

Comment: At a guess it's because you haven't anchored the buttons properly. I assume they should be anchored on their left and bottom sides only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sth like this.

```
DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
```

Comment: Note to self: Leave the Form AutoSize: False